# Sampling Distribution question - Probability finding

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, sampling, combinatorics

> Suppose it is known that 8% of males are color blind. In a random sample of 500 males, what is the approximate probability that at least 10%
>   of them are color blind?

I am doing review for finals and i don't understand how to solve this question. Can anyone help me with this question? 
Answer is

> 0.05

But how?

Comment: Note that for routine textbook style exercises (as might end up in an assignment or set for homework, say) we would normally apply the `self-study` tag. You may like to see its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). (Beyond perhaps including the tag, I think it's probably not necessary to modify your question since you have answered it yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i was able to solve it.

> we know that p-hat equals 0.1 and p equals 0.08.

so basically use the formula

> phat - p/ square-root [p(1-p)/n]

Get the z-score which is

> 1.65

find the corresponding probability from normal table which is

> 0.9505

and since we need atleast 10%, we need the right side of the normal table

> 1 - 0.9505

equals 0.05.

Comment: I find it interesting how different the exact answer is from that given by the normal approximation (the normal approximation with continuity correction does a little better but still isn't especially close; with $np(1-p)$ so large I'd have guessed either would be pretty close - within a percent or so on relative error - in this instance).